# change character encoding of mysql table

Tags: mysql

When I change the character set of a table from utf8 to latin1, the columns still keep the old setting.
For e.g. in the example below, name column is still utf8 even if the table is converted to latin1

```
mysql> create table mytest (id int, name varchar(255)) engine=myisam default charset=utf8;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.02 sec)

mysql> alter table mytest charset=latin1;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.02 sec)
Records: 0  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

mysql> show create table mytest\G
*************************** 1. row ***************************
       Table: mytest
Create Table: CREATE TABLE `mytest` (
  `id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `name` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET utf8 DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

This must be to preseve the data integrity. But is there any way to change everything to latin1. I am not much worried about data. I am ok if there are a few junk characters due to conversion.

Comment: changing the table collation simply changes the default setting, you still need to manually change each current table column for what you want

Comment: you can use the `information_schema` table to select each column and adjust the column collation.